# What is the different of using =, =>, : in react?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm a bit new to react. I can use them with my past experiences. For example, I need sth to describe, I found a similar declaration and use the same shape. But I would like to learn the fundamentals. I mean when should I use below operators;

- const sth : ...
- () => ...
- const sth = ...

If you list the basis of these usages, I would add on them with docs.

Comment: There is no `const sth => ...`  That syntax would be invalid.

Comment: Editted. I mean ;  () => ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are fundamentals of `Javascript` and `Typescript` (or any type definition with js) and not React, please refer to [A re-introduction to JavaScript (JS tutorial)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) in MDN docs.

- [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } // const sth = () => ...
```

- [Assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

```
const sth = ...
```

- [Typescript type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#introduction) or any kind of type definition [like flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/)

```
let isDone: boolean = false;
```

Comment: not only "typescript", but any kind of type definition, e.g. "flow".